# Key points to remember while editing a post

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

On editing any post on Stack Overflow, it shows me this message:

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.

How can I decide if the post needs an edit and the edit is not trivial?

I mean, what are the key points should I remember while editing any post to make it substantial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any edit which would improve the quality of the post is welcome! Though don't make an edit request just to fix one uncapitalized `I`, or fixing a single comma. Try to improve the post overall, by improving its structure, its wording, and/or grammar/spelling. Make sure that it doesn't affect the meaning of original question though.

How would you know? For me, it irks my eye. I can't stand seeing a post with no paragraphs, or posts without capitalization, or without code blocks where needed. That's where I fix. And I try to fix as much as possible in a single edit.

Best way to know? Make many edit requests. See what gets approved by the community, and what not. Best teacher is experience :)

Answer (score 3):

I edit names:

> java, python, jax-rs, Restful, ...

Names like these are written wrong more often than not.

I always edit **trivial language errors** like:

> I am a beginner with Python and I have this problem.

Sentences like this can go.

> ... loaded the code .please help me

I don't know where on the world people switch period and space like this but it can be found very often.

> plz, ur, cuz, ...

English, please.

> ... wrote 2 classes

Up to the number twelve, I prefer words instead of digits.

> Thanks, Regards, Please help! Looking forward for any suggestion.

This is cruft that can be removed.

Comment: Although do all these, just doing the first one should be marked as too minor, and I would have accepted the wording in the second one as seems correct to me although I might treat ir as cruft like the sig as  it does not provide more info about the issue.

Comment: I'll bite - what's the trivial language error in "I am a beginner with Python and I have this problem."?

Comment: @mmyers, it would be accepted better if he had written "I am inexperienced with Python, and have *insert problem* when I do *insert action*.